# opencv native library cannot be found

Tags: java, opencv

I am using an exmplae from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/detect_face_in_image.htm) to apply face recognition using `opencv`. I have extracted opencv at `C:\`. However, after running the provided example cod in Java, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java341 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1865)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
at detectingfaceinanimage.DetectingFaceInAnImage.main(DetectingFaceInAnImage.java:23)
```

I used `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));` to locate path for the java library but I have received numerous paths. Can you let me know how to fix thsi issue? (For Windows platform)

Comment: Do you have downloaded the correct opencv library and have it in your system path?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this issue, needed to copy the `.dll` file from `C:\opencv\build\java\x64` (as I am running a 64 bit operating system) into `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin`.

Comment: According to the programming standards, it is not a good idea to add/edit files or DLLs of the system core or JVM core, there is a way called configuration which I told you in the answer and you downvoted it.  Try to learn a better way to solve problems, not the way to solve one problem and made more problems.

Comment: The file here `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin` you must not change, if you do so, you will be got out from the company as soon as possible by your boss.

Answer (score -2):

You should do these things:

- Add the OpenCV Jar file in your project classpath (I think you
  already did it)
- Locate the OpenCV DLL file location where you extracted it, maybe it
  looks like this:

  **C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin**
- Then add this path in your system environment variable
- In the end, restart your IDE (not your computer), and yes it is that!

Good Luck!!

Comment: What does this part mean?----> `Then add this path in your system environment variable`

Comment: It means: Right-click My Computer -> Properties -> Advance system settings -> Environment Varialbe -> Path -> New -> and then paste that ../../bin path here and then OK -> OK -> OK

Comment: What should be the name for the path? I am pretty sure name is important.

Comment: I have already told you in the answer above. It is the path of the bin folder of the OpenCV, for example, if you installed OpenCV in C:\ drive then, you can go then this folder and then find x64 or x86 folder depends on what your computer architecture is, then vc15 or vc16 folder depends on what version of compiler has used, then bin folder, so the result, it will be something like `C:\opencv\x64\vc15\bin`. Please answer carefully again, then you will find your answer there. Good Luck!

Comment: I didnt say the Value but the name. Cause I have followed your guide and still gets same error

Comment: There is no need name, you do not need to create a new path, you just need to the path in the system path, I think you did not carefully read the answer, I told it very clearly.

Comment: Then add this path in your system environment variable---> when try adding this path, i need to enter a name for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208599/discussion-between-bahramdun-adil-and-lonesome).

Comment: Same issue still exists.